# jQuery .append only moving inner elements of target div

Tags: jquery, append, prepend

I am trying to move, not copy, an html div element via jquery to a different place on the page.

I am currently trying to do this with .append

```
$('#append-options').append($('#wsite-com-product-options').html());
```

This code, wile functioning, is giving me undesirable results. The first issue is that it is only moving the child content inside the #wsite-com-product-price-area div, not the div itself. The second is that this is not simply moving elements, rather copying them, causing the moved element to appear twice on the page.

As may be obvious, I am rather green with jquery. I know there are other ways to move elements in jquery, but I'm not sure which one is appropriate. Here is the full script I am using on my page, which also does a few other things.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('#append-options').append($('#wsite-com-product-options').html());
    $('#insert-after-here').prepend($('#wsite-com-product-price-sale').html());
    $('#insert-after-here').prepend($('#wsite-com-product-price-area').html());
    var $btn = $('#wsite-com-product-buy');
    $('.wsite-product-description').first().append('<div id="something-cool"/>');
    $btn.appendTo('#something-cool').css('top', 0);
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `.html` on it:

```
$('#append-options').append($('#wsite-com-product-options'));
// No `.html()` here --------------------------------------^
```

That will *move* the element itself, including moving its children. It also avoids an unnecessary elements-to-string-then-parse-back-to-elements round-trip, preserving data and event handlers that may be attached to the elements.

Example:

```js
$("input").on("click", function() {
  var target = $("#top").children().length ? "#bottom" : "#top";
  $(target).append($(".moveable"));
});
```

```css
#top {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
#bottom {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.moveable {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <div class="moveable">
      I'm the one that moves.
      Note I have <strong>child elements</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Click to move">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked great @T.J. Crowder. Just curious, what does the .html() actually do, and should I remove it from the other elements of the script?

Comment: @AlexRitter: [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) effectively retrieves the `innerHTML` property of the first element in the jQuery set you call it on. Accessing `innerHTML` asks the browser to spin through all descendant nodes (children and their children, etc.) building up a string of HTML markup that represents them. Unless you want markup, you don't usually want to use `.html()`. You want to work with elements (actual objects), not markup, most of the time. I can't speak for the rest of the script, but you probably don't want it there, no.

Comment: .html() is very much the as the same as the native javascript property innerHTML, it just targets all the html inside of the selected element.